# Is it possible to derive an eos account name from a public key?

Tags: accounts, account-name

Is it possible to derive an eosio account name with just a Public Key?  I am thinking this might be impossible because a single public key can own many accounts, so I don't they have any correlation to each other.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a smart contract? I would like to derive all accounts with a given public key in a smart contract.

Comment: Hi @Alvin ! This response is more appropriate as a comment than an answer. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Hi @Don Peat, thanks for pointing it out. Because I just signed up the account with less than 50 reputations, I am not allowed to leave a comment. That's why I posted it as an answer. You are right, it should not be an ANSWER, I have already posted a question for it and hope someone could help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Using `cleos` you can just run this command:

`cleos --url https://api1.eosdublin.io get accounts <EOS public key>`

This will give you a list of account names associated to that public key.

Otherwise, you can simply search the public key in https://eosflare.io/ or any other EOS block explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Very possible.  EOS Authority will show you what your name is along with many other interesting tidbits with just your public key.  Your name was set at the time your registered your tokens to a random 12 character ID.

https://eosauthority.com/

Comment: Yea but thats using the Ethereum key, I want to use the EOS key